# controlling 2 kw,230v- infra red short wave heaters using electronic device

Tags: voltage-regulator, solid-state-relay, dimming

i want to control infra red short wave heaters 230v,2kw, with some electronic device,
it is an open loop system,where i want to give analog signal to heater from 0 to 100% .
i cant take Thermocouple or RTD or any temperature feedback from heater,due to less space.
i just want to regulate IR heater's power from 0 to 100 %,please suggest me any such device.
thank you.

Comment: How about having a pwm circuit with some power transistors?

Comment: Does it run directly from AC, or does it have an internal power converter? Do you have a model number or further information on this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to talk to the manufacturer.

However, as I understand it, at the simplest level they are just resistive loads, just like normal lamps and as such can be controlled with a high-power (current) version of a normal dimmer.

Dimmers for high-amperage loads are common in the entertainment and architectural lighting industry's you may be able to re-purpose some from there.